# How to keep the div position fixed but it should be still scrollable?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Everyone

I am making an News feed kind of stuff.

I have tried to do it in such a way that when an user scroll the body upto certain level then a category option pops up set in a div like this [Category div example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJRkm.jpg) and its position is fixed so that when there is a scroll up it did not fade away.

Now, there is another div where all the news is displayed like this [News div example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqYiX.jpg)

But the problem is i want the news div also get fixed so that it does not cross the category option div rather it should get fade below the category div but when i tried to set the news feed div position fixed the div is no more scroll and the rest of the news cannot be read but when i keep the news div position relative or absolute the news div get above the category div like this [problem screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sj48m.jpg)

I want result like this [Expected result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tr9i2.jpg) and not like this [not excepting this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWDVa.jpg)

Hope i make everything clear, i known i have not wrote the question clearly sorry for that but is there is any solution that the news div position get fixed below the category div but news div is still scrollable.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

im not 100% sure based on your description but what i think you want is position:sticky; it works like fixed except it fixes itself relative to the viewport not the the html, im not sure if you this is what your after but if you could provide more information and an example of your code so we can better understand what your trying to do i might be able to be more helpful.

Comment: There is no such code i think only setting the element position will do the thing. i want say that in question there are two div one is category div another is news div now i want to fixed category div at the top and when the news feed div is scrolled it is get above the category div as shown in "not expecting image" in the above question, i want the news feed div to scroll from below the category div

Comment: ok set your category to position sticky then set the z-index to 10, then for your news change your z-index to -10. see if that works